# JS / ExtJS 3 Compare width of the text and width of the element in which it is

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I have a combobox:

```
var myCombo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    id: 'myCombo',
    fieldLabel: 'My Combo',
    forceSelection: true,
    valueField: 'id',
    displayField: 'name',
    triggerAction: 'all',
    width: 300,
    mode: 'local',
    store: myStore,
    tpl: '<tpl for="."><tpl if="values.tplRequired != false"><tpl if="this.optGroup != values.optGroup"><tpl exec="this.optGroup = values.optGroup"></tpl><div class="x-combo-list-hd">{optGroup}</div></tpl></tpl><div ext:qtip="{name}<tpl if="values.description != \'\'"> - {description}</tpl>" style="padding-left: 15px;" class="x-combo-list-item">{name}<tpl if="values.description != \'\'"> - {description}</tpl></div></tpl>'
});
```

and some options has too long text ({name} - {description}) so I want to add tooltip with full text to such options.

Is there a way to compare text width with combobox width via ExtJS 3 methods or JS?

If I cant do it via **tpl** how I can loop through all items of the combobox and compare width via ExtJS / JS methods?

Answer (score 1):

I can see 2 solutions:

**the native ext solution**

Use http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.util.Format-method-ellipsis to limit the # of characters used in your results. This will truncate your text nicely when it is necessary only:

```
Ext.util.Format.ellipsis("This is the longest entry I have ever seen in my combo", 20);
=> "This is the longe..."

Ext.util.Format.ellipsis("This is the longest entry I have ever seen in my combo", 20, true);
=> "This is the..."
```

This has the advantage that it can be cut nicely without munching any half words. However it is not width-dependant

**the pure CSS solution**

Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

this is width-dependant so it's probably what you are looking for. However you may not have your text cut the way you want.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Upvoted because I got an interesting and new information for myself, but it does not solve my problem. I have not  to trim the text (this is done by the ExtJS already), but to perform certain actions (add tooltips) for all options, in which the width of the text exceeds the width of the combo.

Comment: @SergeyNovikov were you able to find any solution to this ?

Comment: @coolbuzz This is a very old question, unfortunately I don't remember how I solved this problem. My apologize.